# Regulate ~350V spikes (duration nanoseconds) to logical level 5Volts

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, high-voltage

Use standard 5.1Volt zenerdiode?

Can I trust that with zener diode it wont leak over 5 volts, concerning fast raising high voltage spikes. How about resistor sizing, the input goes to Arduino digital input pin.

The application is bit weird car ignition distributor sensor signal approx 350Volts. Its not the kVolt line which goes to sparkplug.

Comment: put some series inductance and some capacitance. if it really is nanoseconds, it will not pass through that impedance

Comment: I don't think it would be an awful idea to isolate it.  Use an optocoupler to protect the logic side.  It's not clear if you're trying to convert it to a signal of 5v max amplitude or if you simply want 5V out if and only if voltage is at or around 350V.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention. I want to trigger around > 300Volts to logical digital ON (> 2.5volts). Digital pin In has interrupt. Looking for time between spikes (sparks).

Comment: ....and, sorry spike is micro seconds not nanoseconds. Aaaand, optocoupler seems to be best solution, just have to look correct resistor there for 350volts -> ~15mA.